# My problem is "I have to move the cursor (mouse) more up and to the left (1 cm) of the link that i want to open, for really open the link"

Tags: mouse, resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with the respectives updates.

The problem is very simple, but really i want solve it. I suppose that is related with the mouse configuration.

When i clic any link, tab of any window, cell in Openoffice, the clic does not execute. I mean, i have to move the cursor (mouse) more up and to the left (1 cm) of the link that i want to open, for open it. I am not sure if i am explaining well. If i clic exactly in a link, the link does not execute. I have to search the correct place to do it.

The problem affects thunderbird, firefox, openoffice, videos program, etc. With firefox is enough to request advise to solve it.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the mouse is to blame, but the resolution and position of your monitor. I observed something similar on my laptop with an external monitor connected and fiddling around with standby and switching profiles. Just opening system settings helped get things back to normal. If that doesn't help, try to change the resolution manually back and forth. If you use proprietary drivers look for position and multi screen options in the corresponding applications.